# Datepicker does not show at first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've just created a simple `textbox` where inside I binded the `.click` event to show the `Datepicker`, anyway, seems that at first click the `Datepicker` can't show, but if I click outside the control and then click again over the `textbox` I can see the `Datepicker`, I wonder why happen this?

Check out my code here:

```
<input type="text" id="calendar" placeholder="calendar">

$(function()
{
    $('#calendar').click(function()
    {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1811/)

Comment: "_I binded the .click event to show the Datepicker_" Nope. You're adding the "datepicker" functionality on each click of the `#calendar` element.

Comment: The datepicker initialize must be on document.ready(function(){});
Initialize the datepicker to textbox on click of textbox is wrong approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initializing Date picker on your text box click. You have to initialize on document ready method if you want to Open date picker immediate after page load

Change your initializing code to

```
$(function()
{
    $('#calendar').datepicker();
});
```

For your reference [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8w8v9/1813/) updated

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use the click event to start the date picker.
All you have to do is remove the click event and it will work! 
The date picker is already attached to your input box and will handle the events by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `datepicker()` does not invoke the calendar display. What `datepicker()` did was to attach a 'show calendar' event on input-focus. That's the reason why you see the calendar only when you put the focus back on the input field (not on every click of `#calendar` element).

If you want to trigger the display of calendar due to some other event (like button click), you can call `$('#calendar').datepicker('show')`.